# Reusing scheduled & sent emails - screen goes blank

Tags: civimail

Very new at Civi, so please be patient!

Every time we try to reuse an existing email in "scheduled & sent" the screen goes blank. Any ideas?

Have tried different emails, users, browsers, computers and same result. 
We have Civicrm 5.3.1, Joombla Version 3.8.11 stable, Joomla Platform 13.1.0, php 7.1.20, Apache, mysql.

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was somewhere between multi-lingual and logging - `log_civicrm_group` was missing the column `title_en_GB`.  Switching logging off and on again refreshed the log table schema and resolved the blank screen problem.

Comment: This sounds you have been involved with Jeff? Mark the question as solved?

Comment: Yes, it is solved, but it needs Jeff to mark it as such.